# Use Facebook comments widget in bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, facebook-comments

I'm trying to use the Facebook Comments widget inside a bootstrap 2 tab set. If the tab that the comments are placed in isn't the "default" or shown tab, the FB comments iFrame doesn't appear on tab select.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e9QkE/1/

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Is there a way to refresh the tab or trigger the FB iframe on tab select?

Comment: You need to show the comments no matter what `tab` you are and for each `tab` "move" you want this `iframe` to get refreshed, is that correct?

Comment: @OscarJara-- no, I just want the comment to show in the comments tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook comments won't be displayed, if you container is `display:none`, which is the case of non-default tab.

An alternative that I used was to not render the fb comments, until the container is displayed. This can be acheived by using,

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        xfbml:false  // Will stop the fb like button from rendering automatically
    });
};
```

Then to render the fb comments, you can use

```
FB.XFBML.parse(); // This will render all tags on the page

//or the following is a Jquery example on how to render all XFBML within an element

FB.XFBML.parse($('#profile')[0]);   // profile is the id of element which contains the fb code

// In plain js,
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("profile"));
```

***Reference:*** Code from a SO answer.

Comment: @Jashwant-- thanks. In the code you posted, what is the `step2` element? Can you please apply this to my example?

Comment: @Jashwant-- thanks! Would this `FB.XFBML.parse()` go in an `onClick` event attached to the tab?

Comment: Yes, sure. Anytime after the tab is shown. I am pretty sure bootstrap has event which fires after tab is shown. Add this code there. Once, you parse on visible element. You can hide/show it later without doing `FB.XFBML.parse()` again.